# after importing dill and dumping session , the notebook cannot be opened, the code cannot be retrieved

Tags: crash, jupyter-notebook, dill

i worked on some experiment and wanted to find a way to save the lists of data i collected manually. i found dill and decided to use it .

installed via pip. typed in the following code:

```
import dill
dill.dump_session('notebook_env.db')
```

after that i closed the kernel and opened the notebook and to my shocking surprise got the following message:

```
Unreadable Notebook: /Users/nimrodros/Untitled.ipynb UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_import_module\nq\x00X\x08\x00\x00\x00__main__q\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03}q\x04(X\x08\x00\x00\x00__name__q\x05h\x01X\x07\x00\x00\x00__doc__q\x06X@\x00\x00\x00Automatically created module for IPython interactive environmentq\x07X\x0b\x00\x00\x00__package__q\x08NX\x08\x00\x00\x00__spec__q\tNX\x0b\x00\x00\x00__builtin__q\nh\x00X\x08\x00\x00\x00builtinsq\x0b\x85q\x0cRq\rX\x03\x00\x00\x00_ihq\x0e]q\x0f(X\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x10X\x1a\x00\x00\x00eye_correction_middle_fallq\x11X\r\x00\x00\x00fuc=[1,2,3,4]q\x12X\x16\x00\x00\x00eye_correction_voltageq\x13X\r\x00\x00\x00fuc=[1,2,3,4]q\x14X/\x00\x00\x00import dill\ndill.dump_session(\'untitled.ipynb\')q\x15eX\x03\x00\x00\x00_ohq\x16}q\x17X\x03\x00\x00\x00_dhq\x18]q\x19X\x10\x00\x00\x00/Users/nimrodrosq\x1aaX\x02\x00\x00\x00Inq\x1bh\x0fX\x03\x00\x00\x00Outq\x1ch\x17X\x01\x00\x00\x00_q\x1dh\x10X\x02\x00\x00\x00__q\x1eh\x10X\x03\x00\x00\x00___q\x1fh\x10X\x02\x00\x00\x00_iq X\r\x00\x00\x00fuc=[1,2,3,4]q!X\x03\x00\x00\x00_iiq"X\x16\x00\x00\x00eye_correction_voltageq#X\x04\x00\x00\x00_iiiq$X\r\x00\x00\x00fuc=[1,2,3,4]q%%X\x03\x00\x00\x00_i1q&X\x1a\x00\x00\x00eye_correction_middle_fallq\'X\x03\x00\x00\x00_i2q(h%%X\x03\x00\x00\x00fucq)]q*(K\x01K\x02K\x03K\x04eX\x03\x00\x00\x00_i3q+h#X\x03\x00\x00\x00_i4q,h!X\x03\x00\x00\x00_i5q-X/\x00\x00\x00import dill\ndill.dump_session(\'untitled.ipynb\')q.X\x04\x00\x00\x00dillq/h\x00h/\x85q0Rq1ub.', 0, 1, 'invalid start byte')
```

why did this happen , and most importantly , how can i retrieve the code ? that data is already lost probably but i had valuable code there .

i believe if could open the file without running and just erase the line

```
import dill
dill.dump_session('notebook_env.db')
```

then i could again open the file without any problems . so maybe there's a way of doing that?

***update***
i tried to use

```
pip uninstall dill
```

hoped it would run the program again and stop when not recognizing dill , but it didn't go that way . still looking for a solution

***update 2***

tried to run the following on terminal :

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT /Users/nimrodros/Untitled.ipynb -o /Users/nimrodros/New.ipynbh-MacBook-Pro-sl-nimrod:~ nimrodroTRANSLIT /Users/nimrodros/Untitled.ipynb -o /Users/nimrodros/New.ipynb
```

returned the following:

```
cdill._dill
_import_module
q__main__qqRq}q(__name__qhX__doc__qX@Automatically created module for IPython interactive environmentqX
                                     __package__N__spec__q  NX
                                                                  __builtin__q
hbuiltinsq
          q
fuc=[1,2,3,4]qX/import dillon_voltageqX
dill.dump_session('untitled.ipynb')qeX_ohq}qX_dhq]qX/Users/nimrodrofuc=[1,2,3,4]q%X_i1q&Xeye_correction_middle_fallq'X_i2q(h%Xfucq)]q*(KKKKeX_i3q+h#X_i4q,h!X_i5q-X/import dill
dill.dump_session('untitled.ipynb')q.Xdillq/hh/q0Rq1ub.iconv: -o: No such file or directory
iconv: /Users/nimrodros/New.ipynb: No such file or directory
h-MacBook-Pro-sl-nimrod:~ nimrodros$
```

the idea was to just convert it to a file that won't cause the notebook to crash so i could extract the valuable code. any ideas on how to continue?

Comment: How is this related to the D programming language?

Comment: must've accidently added the tag.

Comment: so no one is replying to my post and i'm not sure what to do about it . it's a serious problem and maybe someone else would experience it , it's definitely caused by the dill module so if anyone reaches this post i recommend not using that module .

Comment: Did you try something as trivial as - convert the `/Users/nimrodros/Untitled.ipynb` file to UTF-8 ... On Linux something like `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT /Users/nimrodros/Untitled.ipynb -o /Users/nimrodros/New.ipynb` would do (assuming your file is encoded using ISO-8859-1)

Comment: i think your suggestion applies to mac as well , so i tried it and got another message i do not understand . i added it to the original post as an update .

Comment: The command line is incorrect. What is that `-o /Users/nimrodros/New.ipynbh-MacBook-Pro-sl-nimrod:~ nimrodroTRANSLIT /Users/nimrodros/Untitled.ipynb` ??